# Hotbit REST API's PUT_LIMIT function gives error RET_SIGN_ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-requests, cryptocurrency, hashlib

So basically the hotbit's documentation you can find on

https://github.com/hotbitex/hotbit.io-api-docs/blob/master/readme_en.md

https://github.com/hotbitex/hotbit.io-api-docs/blob/master/rest_api_en.md#orderput_limit

a point need to be remember in hashing SIGN parameter is :
sort the strings that require to be signed according to the parameter names（first compare the first letter of all parameter names and sort them based on alphabetical order; in case that the first letter of more than one parameters is the same, sort these parameters based on the second letter of their names according to alphabetical order, and so on)

parameters that need to be hashed according to alphabets are api_key, secret_key, market, isfee, market, price, amount

```
import hashlib, requests

url = "https://api.hotbit.io/v2/p2/order.put_limit"

sign_string = "amount=" + str(amount) + "&api_key=" + str(api_key) +  "&isfee=0&market=" +  str(market) +  "&price=" + str(price) + "&secret_key=" + str(secret_key) + "&side=" + str(side)

sign = hashlib.md5(sign_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
sign = sign.upper()


body = {
  "api_key" : str(api_key), 
  "amount" : amount,
  "isfee" : 0 ,
  "market" :   str(market),
  "price" : price,
  "side" : side,
  "sign": str(sign)   }


params = "?amount=" + str(amount) + "&api_key=" + str(api_key) +  "&isfee=0&market=" +  str(market) +  "&price=" + str(price) + "&side=" + str(side) + "&sign=" + str(sign)
print (params)

response = requests.request('POST', url, data = body )


print (response.text)
```

and here is the response we get from Hotbit API

```
{"error":{"code":6,"message":"RET_SIGN_ERROR"},"result":null,"id":0}
```

Please help me solving this problem..!
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: How you got api credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Ohk so i got answer what was wrong in it you can compare your code , (sign_string was not configured properly in alphabetical order)

```
  ORDER_PUT_LIMIT = "https://api.hotbit.io/v2/p2/order.put_limit"
    
    
    def sell(self, amount=0, price=0, market=settings.MARKET, isfee=settings.ISFEE):
            """
            Response:
            {
                "error": null,
                "result": 
                {
                "id":8688803,    #order-ID
                    "market":"ETHBTC",
                    "source":"web",    #The source identification of data request
                    "type":1,          #Type of order pladement 1-limit order
                    "side":2,          #Identification of buyers and sellers 1-Seller，2-buyer
                    "user":15731,
                    "ctime":1526971722.164765, #Time of order establishment(second)
                    "mtime":1526971722.164765, #Time of order update(second)
                    "price":"0.080003",
                    "amount":"0.4",
                    "taker_fee":"0.0025",
                    "maker_fee":"0",
                    "left":"0.4",
                    "deal_stock":"0",
                    "deal_money":"0",
                    "deal_fee":"0",
                    "status":0    , #Sign of order status when 0x8 is true, it means the current order is cancelled, when 0x80 is true, it means that the current order is deducted by deductable tokens        "fee_stock":"HTB",  #Name of deductable token
                    "alt_fee":"0.5",    #The discount of deductable tokens
                    "deal_fee_alt":"0.123" #Amount deducted
                    },
                "id": 1521169460
            }
            """
    
            side = 1 # 1 for sell and 2 for buy
                
            sign_string = "amount=" + str(amount) + "&api_key=" + str(settings.API_KEY) +  "&isfee=0&market=" +  str(market) +  "&price=" + str(price) + "&side=" + str(side) + "&secret_key=" + str(settings.SECRET_KEY)
    
            sign = hashlib.md5(sign_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            sign = sign.upper()
            
            body = {
                "api_key" : str(settings.API_KEY), 
                "amount" : amount,
                "isfee" : 0 ,
                "market" :   str(market),
                "price" : price,
                "side" : side,
                "sign": str(sign)   }
            
            response = requests.post(ORDER_PUT_LIMIT, data=body, headers=HEADERS).json()
            print(response)
            return response
```

and my problem was solved..
The api_key and private key are saved in settings.py file.